# Plotting this weeks data versus last weeks in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a datasets structured the following way

```
date    transaction 
8/15/2020   585
8/14/2020   780
8/13/2020   1427.8
8/12/2020   4358
8/11/2020   780.9
8/8/2020    585
8/6/2020    1107.4
8/5/2020    2917.35
8/4/2020    1237.1
```

Is there a way to plot a line graph with all the transactions that occurred this week compared to the previous week? I tried filtering the data manually and assigning it to a new dataframe which seemed to work but its very manual intensive. Would it be possible to use today() and have it register the day of execution and run the results from there? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that, you need

1. real `Date` (using `as.Date`), so that we can deal with them numerically (not categorically), and so that we can break them into weeks;
2. use `format` to get each date's week-of-the-year; and
3. `facet_wrap` so that we can use facets and have distinct x axes.

```r
dat$date <- as.Date(dat$date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
dat$week <- format(dat$date, format = "%V") # or %W

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(date, transaction)) +
  facet_wrap("week", ncol = 1, scales = "free_x") +
  geom_path()
```

[image: ggplot2 with facets by-week]

Comment: Cool thanks! Two last things how do I limit the output to just display this and the previous week if my data set has the whole year? Can I have the axis be labeled with the actual day instead of the month and number?

Comment: (1) If you look at `dat`, you'll see `week`, you can use any form of `data.frame` subsetting/filtering to show only this and last week. (2) Yes, look at `scale_x_date(..., labels=)` (and many questions on SO about formatting `Date` axes), and `?strptime` informs this as well. Try `+ scale_x_date(date_labels = "%a")` added to the above.

Comment: Excellent, I filtered the data with filter() and manually selected week >= 33 and worked smoothly. Im going to play with it and try a nest a today() and select the last two. Can I plot values that yield no values with a 0 for example for Sundays or does it need to be implicit as a 0 in the data?

Comment: While one could argue that *"no data available"* and *"value of zero"* are two different things ... yes. In this case, it might be imputation, conditional replacement, or a few other things.

Comment: I tried plotting it on the same graph using (color ="week") but I just got a single line of both weeks instead of Sunday - Saturday with two lines

Comment: To plot them both overlapping without facets, you'll need to use `aes(dayofweek, transacvtion)` (and you'll need to define `dat$dayofweek`).

Comment: got the dat$dayofweek set but the ggplot is still all wonky, it has the days of the week by alphabetical order and the values are just vertical lines :S dat %>%
  filter(week >= 32) %>%
  ggplot(aes(dayofweek, transaction, color="week")) +
  geom_path()

Comment: Ordering in `ggplot2` is always done either (a) alphabetically when the values are `character`; or (b) the order you specify when they are `factor`. `factor(dat$dayofweek, levels=c("Mon","Tue",...))`?

Comment: that's what I figured afterwards, thanks for the help!